# Is it possible to have a proven memory leak that does not result in out of memory event

Tags: java

The memory leak is identified but it does not result in OOM event to create a heap dump

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up

Comment: Does it crash the app? Or are you impatient and leaking a byte every hour and have gigabytes of available memory ?

Comment: I think you need to add more parameters to your question. E.g. is it a simple program you're talking about? A server application? An android app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Out of memory will happen when there is not enough memory left to allocate new objects.

Simplified, this could happen either intentionally (try to process too much data in one go), or unintentional (by forgetting to release used memory).

Usually when causing out of memory events, some resource(s) are continuously used without being released. Eventually leading to a out of memory event.

If the resource is infrequently used you may not leak enough memory to deplete the available memory for your application.
Or it just will take a very long time until causing out of memory, hours, days, weeks or months.